# How do i use variables in urlretrieve in place of the destination file

Tags: python, urllib

i am not getting the proper result

running the code using various variable values

```
import urllib.request
x=input("enter the source link") # from where the file is to be downloaded
y=input("enter the destination address") # where the file is to be saved
z=input("enter file name") # the name by which you wish to save
s=input("enter extension type") # the extension of the file
url = x  # from where the file is to be downloaded
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'y/z.s') # using variables to write the destination 

print('Beginning file download') # ensure success of above code
```

i am getting an error in output due to line 7 in destination folder

following error

---

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f187f3520048> in <module>
      5 s=input("enter extension type") # the extension of the file
      6 url = x  # from where the file is to be downloaded
----> 7 urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'y/z.s') # using variables to write the destination
      8 
      9 print('Beginning file download') # ensure success of above code

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    255         # Handle temporary file setup.
    256         if filename:
--> 257             tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
    258         else:
    259             tfp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'y/z.s'
```

please guide

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

You use them in the same way as you would in any other string; by concatenation or interpolation.

```
'{}/{}.{}'.format(y, z, s)
```

or

```
f'{y}/{z}.{s}
```

or

```
y + '/' + z + '.' + s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f'{x}:{y}'
```

use format for concat str.
or use + operator dreactly.